# How to define an Order Preserving Bijection $f$ from rationals to rationals such that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$ that is not the identity function

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, logic

I need to define a bijection $f:\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q$ such that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$ while also preserving order (i.e. if $a < b$, then $f(a) < f(b)$). Also, $f$ cannot be the identity function.

Whenever I try to come up with a function, it either becomes not injective, not surjective, or it does not preserve order. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Define it as the identity on the nonnegative rationals, and as $q\mapsto \frac{q}{2}$ on the negative ones.

Comment: Don't just change the question. Accept the answer you think best answers your question. Otherwise, what is the point for anybody but you? I rolled back your edit.

Comment: You have completely changed the question, invalidating two good answers to the one you asked before.  If you can't ask another, it is because it is too soon.  Just wait a while.

Comment: As for your edited question (the one that has been rolled back), make sure to search if the question has been asked already. There are plenty of examples of explicit bijections between $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Q$ to be found on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are plenty of examples. The following function $f:\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q$ is one example: $$f(x) = \begin{cases}2x&x<0\\x&x\geq0\end{cases}$$Now, if you also require that the bijection preserves addition/multiplication, then such a map doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is just to use two straight lines.
$$f(x)= \begin {cases} \frac x2 & x \le \frac 12\\
\frac 14+\frac 32(x-\frac 12)& \frac 12 \lt x\end{cases}$$
[[image]

Comment: $x^3$ does not work (it needs to be a bijection on the rationals, not the reals)

Comment: Not just any straight lines, they need to have a rational slope.